# In blazor component, focus in input text, how to make tab key to move focus to options drop-down?

Tags: blazor

I type something in the input field, the options narrowed. Then, by pressing tab the focus skips options drop-down. I want it to jump to options list. I have a sample below. Can it be done by html attributes only? if no, how can i do it in blazor?

I know up & down keys do that. But I feel it's faster and more intuitive for tab key.

```
<input type="text" @bind="@newStudyCode" list="studies" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search ..." />
<datalist id="studies">
        @if (Studies != null)
        {
            @foreach (var study in Studies)
            {
                <option value="@study.Code">@study.Code - @study.Title</option>
            }
        }
    </datalist>
```

the compiled html is looking like this

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" list="browsers" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search ...">
  <datalist id="browsers">
            <option value="Firefox" tabindex="1">
                Firefox
            </option>
            <option value="Internet" tabindex="2">
                Internet
            </option>
            <option value="Chrome" tabindex="3">
                Chrome
            </option>
            <option value="Safari" tabindex="4">
                Safari
            </option>
  </datalist>
  <button type="submit">Push me</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle just said, you just need tabindex

```
 <input type="text" @bind="@newStudyCode" list="studies" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Search ..." /> 
    <datalist id="studies"> 
       @if (Studies != null) 
          { 
            var i =1;
            @foreach (var study in Studies) 
               { 
                  <option value="@study.Code" tabindex="@i">
                    @study.Code - @study.Title
                  </option
                  i++;
               }
            } 
      </datalist>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, please see here https://jsfiddle.net/krgyxd7h/2/

Answer (score -1):

This can be done just using regular html `tabindex` attribute. Nothing special for blazor needed.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" tabindex="2">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" tabindex="1">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/" tabindex="3">Microsoft</a>
```

See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: This doesn't work, please see here, https://jsfiddle.net/krgyxd7h/2/.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. I misunderstood your question. You want to tab through the option list? To me that is not intuitive, but I think it should be possible. I think your only option would be to use javascript with JsInterop, and capture the tab key and on key press check the input its currently on, and move to the next one.

Comment: I want the focus move like that  input text --(tab)--> options drop-down --(tab)--> button. But i think you are right i have to resort to JS.